# How to parse the description part in a CSV file and read only from column headers in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, metadata

Hi I have a dataframe which is a csv file, the first few rows consists of description or meta data. How to parse the file from the data and not the description.

How can i read the file and parse it?

[image: Dataset with description]

This is general description of studies

A        B              C      D
Pharma   Retail         IoT   Supply Chain
Medical  Manufacturing  CV    Health

Here between the description and the data starting, there are 3 rows gap. Likewise it might vary, dynamically how can i parse only the data

Comment: With the `skiprows` parameter of `pd.read_csv`

Comment: Can you elaborate it with the code? And also the description can vary as well, there is no fixed rows for description

Comment: No, I can't. I would need to know how many rows to skip in which files or how to recognise a row that should be script. Also I would need reproducible example(s) to try code out on. Neither of those were in your question...

Comment: Okay i can add it, i have shared the file. Its the same. I want to dynamically parse the data where the column names start

Comment: I have added in the question. Let me know how to dynamically parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [skiprows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) argument to skip your metadata.

Comment: What should be the value given in skiprows? and does it work even if the description rows varies?

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)

Comment: Thanks, what is usecols=field?

Comment: usecols is supposed to provide a filter before reading the whole DataFrame into memory; if used properly, there should never be a need to delete columns after reading.